# Use slice3D() from package plot3D

Tags: r, plot3d

I am trying to use the package `plot3D` to plot my xyz data with the color based on 4th variable.

My  data looks like this:

```
data.frame(xx,yy,zz,Ammpl)
           xx       yy           zz Ammpl
1    63021.71 403105.0  1.181028516  1170
2    63021.71 403105.0  0.977028516  1381
3    63021.71 403105.0  0.861028516   807
4    63021.71 403105.0  0.784028516   668
5    63021.71 403105.0  0.620028516 19919
6    63021.71 403105.0  0.455028516 32500
7    63021.71 403105.0  0.446028516 32500
8    63021.71 403105.0  0.436028516 32500
9    63021.71 403105.0  0.426028516 32500
10   63021.71 403105.0  0.281028516 17464
```

First thing I did was use from the package `akima` the function `interp`. To create a regular grid

```
s100<-interp(xx,yy,zz, xo=seq(min(xx):max(xx), length=30, yo=seq(min(yy):max(yy), length=30), duplicate="mean")
```

From the package `plot3D` in used the function `slice3D`

```
slice3D(x = s100$x, y = s100$y, z = s100$z,  colvar = ampl, 
ys = 1:10, zs = NULL, NAcol = "black", 
expand = 0.4, theta = 45, phi = 45)
```

My problem is I don't know how to build data `ampl` for  `colvar` so it will provide the colouring in this plot.

I have tried a lot of things but I thinks this is where I get stuck.

In `example(slice3D)` they use `oxsat$val` from  `data(oxsat)` to create the `colvar`.

```
> dim(Oxsat$val)
[1] 180  90  33
```